# Windows Registry file association menu

Tags: windows, delphi, registry, shell-extensions

I have recently(today) began meddeling with my registry from within Delphi. :)
all is working well and my custom file type now opens with my program, but there are 2 issues i can't solve.

1) I wanted the option to "open with" from all file types so i added

```
  reg := TRegistry.Create;
  reg.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
  reg.LazyWrite := false;
  reg.OpenKey('*\OpenWithList\EncryptionSystem', true);
  reg.WriteString('','C:\Program Files\EncryptionSystem\EncryptionSystem.exe "%1"');
  reg.CloseKey;
  reg.free;
```

If I look in the registry using regedit it's sure there as it should seem to be but when I right click on a file and select Open With it's not there...

So I then added this

```
  reg.OpenKey('*\shell\Encrypt\command', true);
  reg.WriteString('','C:\Program Files\EncryptionSystem\EncryptionSystem.exe "%1"');
  reg.CloseKey;
```

This does work for every file but the option is right at the top with "open" and "edit".
I kinda want it to appear in a menu subsection like most programs do...
I realised that i needed to play with shellext but i did not understand the structure of how these worked withing the context menu handlers... I'd learnt all I had from reading the registry anyway... I know the name for the shellext appears later after the ".*" but as for the meaning of the big jibberish keys I have no idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the "Open with" menu is not populated by that registry key alone. It's trumped by an extension-specific list stored by Explorer at the following location:

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts

I'd venture a guess that the list you're adding your application to is only used if Explorer doesn't have anything better to use — so only for files that don't already have their own "Open with" lists defined.

Also, it looks like an "Open with" registry entry is supposed to have a different form from the one you're using. The key should be the name of the EXE file, such as *ExcryptionSystem.exe*. The default value for that key, if present, should be an empty string. I'm basing this just on what I see in the registry on my own system.

You should take a look at the [File Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144148.aspx) MSDN article, part of the [Introduction to File Associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144104.aspx).

Comment: yea the addition of the .exe extention and the removal of the data link within the regestry entry seems to have fixed it,,lol i dont know how as the data link was telling it where ti was. meh....

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the registry it looks like it your line should be changed to.

From

```
reg.OpenKey('*\OpenWithList\EncryptionSystem', true);
reg.WriteString('','C:\Program Files\EncryptionSystem\EncryptionSystem.exe "%1"')
```

to

```
reg.OpenKey('*\OpenWithList\EncryptionSystem.exe', true); //note exe
reg.WriteString('','C:\Program Files\EncryptionSystem\EncryptionSystem.exe "%1"')
```

Check this first.

Answer (score 0):

On my W7P they're not as referenced.  Instead they're at...

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```