# How to add application in "Open with..." section of system menu in Windows 7?

Tags: delphi, registry, key

Real problem and question is:
How to add key in Registry hive "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" in Windows 7?

I know where to create the key, but it can be achieved only when I run program as an administrator. Or manually... :) 
Otherwise, error message appears which says that is not possible to add/create the key.

Is this possible without admin privileges?

Location of that key:
"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\MyAppName.exe\shell\open\comand"

Code that I use to write in Registry:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
   Reg: TRegistry;
   appfilename: string;
begin
appfilename:= application.ExeName;
reg := TRegistry.Create;
reg.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
if not reg.KeyExists('Applications\MyAppName.exe\shell\open\command') then
begin
 if reg.OpenKey('Applications\MyAppName.exe\shell\open\command', True) then
 begin
  reg.WriteString('', '"' + appfilename + '" "%1"');
  reg.CloseKey;
 end;
end;
```

end;

Comment: You have a serious memory leak. You have to free the `TRegistry` object. Use `try..finally`.

Comment: Just an idea: isn't this a job for your setup utility, which anyway is run with raised privileges?

Comment: Ok, TRY and FINALLLY must be in the code, but adding that does not help. I belive that this is possible in XP or later Win OS.

Comment: I can change privileges, but that is not a solution, because that will work only for this, my PC...

Comment: You can use a manifest, also. But why not do this during setup?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/590892/62576

Comment: I thought that this could be easily done, but it seems that is not so easy. I'll try to use the manifest. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enter the key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`. This will be copied to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` by Windows.

Comment: It won't be copied anywhere. HKCR is a merged view. It's virtual. No copying.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that this will be usefull for someone. This is the way to add your app in "Open with..." section of system menu in Windows 7 (I did not check this on others OS). 
Thanks to @John Clement, here is the answer:

```
procedure TForm1.AddAppInOpenWith;
var Reg: TRegistry;
         appfilename: string;
begin
  appfilename:= application.ExeName;
  reg := TRegistry.Create;
  reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
  try
  if not reg.KeyExists('Software\Classes\Applications\AppName.exe\shell\open\command') then
  begin
    if reg.OpenKey('Software\Classes\Applications\AppName.exe\shell\open\command', True) then
    begin
      reg.WriteString('', '"' + appfilename + '" "%1"');
      reg.CloseKey;
    end;
  end;
  finally Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```